# how do I make a date count-up like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make a clock/callendar like in this webpage.

https://uawar.net/stats

I do not know if this requires js in my html codes. But when I inspected the webpage the div-counter time, I was the '' and the time flashing in purple.

how do I make a clock/callendar just like that?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It's flashing because the innerHTML of that element is being updated every second. Investigate Javascript's date and time functions, have a go at coding this and if still stuck put the code you have so far into your question with a description of what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need both HTML and Javascript for your functions to run with real-time date and time.

Here is an example:
Then you need to add javascript functions for their updation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Countdown Timer</title>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="countdown">
        <span id="days">00</span>:
        <span id="hrs">00</span>:
        <span id="min">00</span>:
        <span id="sec">00</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a setInterval function to make the clock live

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).